# How to edit drive partitions for dual booting?

Tags: partition, windows, dual-boot

I need to install Ubuntu on my new laptop for some development. I want to dualboot, which I've done a few time before, however I'm having some trouble with the partitioning. There are lots of partitions on the drive, most of which I'm not sure what they do.

Here is a picture of the partitions. Could someone tell me how to edit the drive to allow me to do this?

[image]

Comment: If you want to continue to use Windows, and you want your Lenovo recovery partitions, there's nothing available to delete.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://askubuntu.com/a/371605/157358) you can find some info about what the flags on the partitions mean. Adding to that, WinRE is the [Windows Recovery Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Preinstallation_Environment#Windows_Recovery_Environment), and it is usual on laptop to come with a partition containing some propretary software (like the LENOVO in your case).

If you're not sure, don't remove the other partitions, just reduce the main one (sda5 in your case, judging by the size). To do this you can either use the embedded disk partition tool from windows (see for example [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/101862/how-to-manage-partitions-on-windows-without-downloading-any-other-software/)), or gparted from ubuntu (there are a lot of guides about this process, see for example [WindowsDualBoot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) or [HowToResizeWindowsPartitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoResizeWindowsPartitions),

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, for some reason gparted won't let me reduce the size of the partition. Which is why I'm having trouble installing, sorry I should have been more clear.

Comment: why not? what error does it give? did you try to reduce it from windows?